# Battery drops down suddenly

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging

I have purchased a LENOVO YOGA 300 recently. The battery discharges from 95% to 45 % normally and suddenly jumps to 7%.

Pl suggest. Its just 2 month old Laptop.

Comment: Bad battery? Try getting a new one

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the battery.

Comment: Looks like a faulty Battery try to claim with Warranty

Comment: If it is 2 months old, it should still be under warranty. Contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Battery. Warranty.  Sorry -- just wanted to join in... ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Your suggestion is very valuable :)

Answer (score 5):

Your battery *could* be faulty, and at that age, its certainly under warranty.

However, before you find your local service center for the laptop, you should probably try caliberating the battery. If you have the usual thinkpad power control application, its there - otherwise, it seems you can do it from something called one key optimiser.

If caliberation dosen't work, check about a battery replacement . Better to get it done early and to make lenovo pay for it, than to put it off.